# abrupt end of program while fflush in c

Tags: fflush

So I was doing an assignment for a class in which I have to perform basic
array functions for an array of structures and in taking input my
program closed on its own. The program terminated after taking input of name

```
void input(struct record *d){
printf("\nenter name: ");
fflush(stdin);
gets(d->name);
printf("\nenter adress: ");
fflush(stdin);
gets(d->adress);
printf("\nEnter mobile no :");
scanf("%s",d->mobile);
printf("\nenter marks:");
scanf("%if",d->marks);
printf("\nenter cgpa: ");
scanf("%if",d->cgp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The record structure must be initialized, and you should use

```c
 scanf("%if", &(d->marks));
  printf("\nenter cgpa: ");
  scanf("%if", &(d->cgp));
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct record
{
  char name[255];
  char adress[2048];
  char mobile[80];
  int marks;
  int cgp;
} record;

void input(struct record *d)
{
  printf("\nenter name: ");
  fflush(stdin);
  gets(d->name);
  printf("\nenter adress: ");
  fflush(stdin);
  gets(d->adress);
  printf("\nEnter mobile no :");
  scanf("%s", d->mobile);
  printf("\nenter marks:");
  scanf("%if", &(d->marks));
  printf("\nenter cgpa: ");
  scanf("%if", &(d->cgp));
}

void print_record(record *r)
{
  printf("Name: %s\r\n", r->name);
  printf("Adress: %s\r\n", r->adress);
  printf("Mobile %s\r\n", r->mobile);
  printf("Marks %i\r\nf", r->marks);
  printf("Cgp %if\r\n", r->cgp);
}

int main()
{

  record r1;
  input(&r1);
  print_record(&r1);
}
```

Comment: The program end because of a segmentation fault.